# RichTextBox incorrect behavoir with private fonts

Tags: c#, fonts, richtextbox

Using RichTextBox with private fonts I've encountered following problem: I'm able to write the text with my private font inside the text box, but when I select it(need it further in my program) text box return MS Sans Serif as Selection font.

```
PrivateFontCollection pfc = new PrivateFontCollection(); // font collection
pfc.AddFontFile("..\\..\\Fonts\\infotra1.ttf"); // load font
rtb.Font = new Font(pfc.Families[0], 10.0f, FontStyle.Regular);
rtb.AppendText("lorem ipsum bla bla bla\n");
```

Now, text is correctly appended into the text box.

> private void rtb_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
>         var f = rtb.SelectionFont; }

If I select the text and inspect rtb.SelectionFont it returns MS Sans Serif.

I know that system returns MS Sans Serif when it's unable to find my font. Should I tell to RichTextBox in some way that I'm using also my private fonts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably working as expected but you need to look at `f.OriginalFontName` instead of `f.Name` to realise it since you are using private fonts.

Looking into the Font Documentation ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/164w6x6z ) I found this:

> If the familyName parameter specifies a font that is not installed on
>   the machine running the application or is not supported, **Microsoft
>   Sans Serif will be substituted**.